# Excel 2010 populate based on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need some help with dynamic range and auto populate.
I have a sheet with 2 Columns, 1 is the name and the other is the age between 6 and 12. There are 20 rows.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO3u2.jpg

In another sheet i have created 6 columns age 6 to 12.
The idea is to auto populate those rows based on the age and when the age changes the kid is moved to the corresponding column.
Here is the formula iv used

=IF(ROWS(A$2:A2)<=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$20;A$1);INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$20;SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$20=A$1;ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$20)-ROW('Sheet1'!$B$1)+1);ROWS(A$2:A2)));"")

But it isn't working. Where am I going wrong?

I am using this youtube video as a reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp7I5u1MqiM